# Is there any way to trigger a HTML dropdown using a image on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

What I am trying to do is trigger a HTML drop-down via an image (the standard three line menu image).  Phones seem to handle the HTML drop-down well and I would rather use the native solution than anything else.  I currently have this as my jquery that creates the drop down when a mobile site is pulled up, but I would rather it not look like a drop down list.  Anyway to do this?

```
// Create the dropdown base
$("<select id='comboNav' />").appendTo("#combo-holder");

// Create default option "Go to..."
$("<option />", {
    "selected": "selected",
    "value"   : "",
    "text"    : "Navigation"
}).appendTo("#combo-holder select");

// Populate dropdown with menu items
$("#nav a").each(function() {
    var el = $(this);       
    var label = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var sub = (label == 'nav') ? '' : '- ';

    $("<option />", {
     "value"   : el.attr("href"),
     "text"    :  sub + el.text()
    }).appendTo("#combo-holder select");
});

 $('.select_button1').click(function() {
$('#comboNav').toggle();
  });
```

Here is the HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="select_button1">Click Me!</a> <div id="combo-holder">
                    <!-- Headline -->
                    <div id="headline">

                    </div>
                    <!-- ENDS headline -->          

                </div>
```

Comment: To answer your question:  Yes, I am positive there is a way...

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence Doorhandle.